# pass to the SSRS report multiple integer values

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I try to pass to a SSRS report, from the C# code multiple arrays of integer

```
var rsExec = new ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(config.ReportExecutionUrl));

ParameterValue[] reportParam = new ParameterValue[] {
    new ParameterValue { Name = "pCityId", Value = cityId.ToString() },
    new ParameterValue { Name = "pDepartmentIds", Value = string.Join(",", departmentIds) },
    new ParameterValue { Name = "pBuildingIds", Value = string.Join(",", buidingIds) }
};

await rsExec.SetExecutionParametersAsync(null, null, reportParam, "en-us");
```

[image]

as the Value type of ParameterValue is "string", it seems I have no choice but passing a CSV as parameter to the report.

Then, in the report I can use data type as integer, and say that I am passing "multiple values", but how to do it from the C# code?

[image]

PS. Related to that [question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5b7d9713-8bde-4360-9680-503db0ed2d70/passing-multiple-integer-values-as-parameter-in-ssrs?forum=sqlreportingservices)

Comment: Multiple values would be an array in c# : new ParameterValue { Name = "pBuildingIds", Value =  new int[] {1,2,3,4} }

Comment: @jdweng thanks, as mentioned, Value is of String type

Comment: The type in SSRS has to match the c#.  The picture showed integer (not string).

Comment: the picture is from SSRS side. The string is on the C# side...

Comment: explain: I need to send an array of integer from the C# side, how to do it, if the "value" is of String type

Comment: The value is not string.  The picture shows INTEGER.

Comment: @jdweng I send from C# a string, I have no other choice from C#. But in SSRS can be string, or integer, that is you see in picture, is SSRS side, not the C# one. In picture is SSRS, but in C# Value is of "string" type

Comment: You are sending parameters.  There is a driver in SSRS and a driver in c# (SQLClient) that communicates and the types must be the same on both ends of the connection.  If SSRS has INTEGERS than c# must send INTEGERS.  The value of the parameter is treated as an object which must be an integer array.

Comment: "c# must send INTEGERS"... maybe it "must", but *how* to send them as integers? The type of the `Value` property of `ParameterValue` is "String" I am talking now about C# side, once again, not the picture

Comment: Really?  The following says object : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.value?force_isolation=true&view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Comment: @jdweng that is a SqlParameter.Value, nothing to do with SSRS  ParameterValue.Value: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/reportexecution2005.parametervalue.value?view=sqlserver-2016#ReportExecution2005_ParameterValue_Value

Comment: That link is for the server (not c# code).  The link also contradicts the form that you posted.  The form and the link on both on the server side. the form is handling the integer array.

Comment: @jdweng, Updated the OP to show you the code...

Comment: I have the C# code that calls a SOAP service that generates the report.

Comment: The drive handle the type conversion. It does not need to be string.  The Example link says : Select "Allow multiple values" and set data type to Integer. Multi-value parameters deliver the values as an array. The query interface is smart enough to convert them to the proper syntax (comma-delimited) automatically so a statement like:
WHERE Field IN (@id)

Comment: if I pass from C# "1,2,3" as value of a parameter, declared in SSRS as integer with multiple values, I have the runtime error: "The value provided for the report parameter 'pYourIds' is not valid for its type."

Comment: See last posting on following :https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a2792c1d-f748-4a14-8222-cda2c439963b/pass-integer-array-to-code-function-in-ssrs?forum=sqlreportingservices&force_isolation=true

Comment: I think that what you need to do is send a `ParameterValue` for each value in the `departmentIds` collection, all with the same parameter name ("pDepartmentIds"). So, if there was 3 department IDs to send, the `reportParam` array should contain 3 `ParameterValue` objects, all with the name "pDepartmentIds", one for each department ID. Similar for `buildingIds`.

Comment: @R.Richards I will check that, interesting idea

Comment: @R.Richards, could you please make from your comment an answer? It works as you suggested, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To send parameters where the *Allow multiple values* option is selected, you need to send a new `ParameterValue` object for each value that is going to be consumed by the report, all with the same `Name`.

In the case described above, you need to send a `ParameterValue` for each value in the `departmentIds` collection, all with the same parameter name ("pDepartmentIds").

So, if there was 3 department IDs to send, the `reportParam` array should contain 3 `ParameterValue` objects, all with the name "pDepartmentIds", one for each department ID.

```
ParameterValue[] reportParam = new ParameterValue[] {
    new ParameterValue { Name = "pCityId", Value = cityId.ToString() },
    new ParameterValue { Name = "pDepartmentIds", Value = "1" },
    new ParameterValue { Name = "pDepartmentIds", Value = "2" },
    new ParameterValue { Name = "pDepartmentIds", Value = "3" },
    ...
};
```

Do something similar for `buildingIds`.

Comment: optionally, the type of the parameter can be set as "integer", even if the value type is string, the type will be inferred in the report as double or integer...

Comment: I thought that might be the case. Leaves it to the report to validate the values passed in. I am glad this helped you. I had to dig to find an old SSRS solution I wrote a while back to remember this. For a while, I thought the code was lost. I will be getting that into git this week.

Comment: yeah, that really helped, cause before that I only could use CSV values to pass an array of integers and then needed parse it back in SSRS, that was not really cool... now is OK